# Between writing fuzzing tests with echidna vs writing fuzzing tests with foundry, are there any advantages one has over the other?

Tags: solidity, evm, foundry, echidna, fuzz-test

Deciding which tool to use to write some fuzzing tests, was curious if one tool or the other performs better at fuzz testing than the other. It seems to me that foundry will be easier to setup my local environment with since I can fork and active evm chain and run tests on it, but I'm curious if echidna has a higher throughput for fuzzing/randomness. Anyone have any insight on the pros/cons of each tool?

Comment: See the discussion I have started on Twitter about this: [Is there any benefit in using Echidna over the default fuzzing that comes with Forge?](https://twitter.com/PaulRBerg/status/1617449048608313349). And also see this: [echidna-vs-forge](https://github.com/clabby/echidna-vs-forge).

Comment: Interesting stuff, thanks!